# R Compare each data value of a column to rest of the values in the column?

Tags: r

I would like to create a function that looks at a column of values. from those values look at each value individually, and asses which of the other data points value is closest to that data point.
I'm guessing it could be done by checking the length of the data frame, making a list of the respective length in steps of 1. Then use that list to reference which cell is being analysed against the rest of the column. though I don't know how to implement that. 
eg.
data:

1. 20
2. 17
3. 29
4. 33

   - 1) is closest to 2)
   - 2) is closest to 1)
   - 3) is closest to 4)
   - 4) is closest to 3)

I found this example which tests for similarity but id like to know what letter is assigns to.

```
x=c(1:100)
your.number=5.43
which(abs(x-your.number)==min(abs(x-your.number)))
```

Also if you know how I could do this, could you expain the parts of the code and what they mean?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but if `v <- c(20, 17, 29, 33)`, how about something like `apply(outer(v, v, function(x, y) abs(x - y)), 1, function(x) order(x)[2])`?

Comment: Or `x <- c(20, 17, 29, 33) ; cbind(x, closest = sapply(seq_along(x), function(y) x[-y][which.min(abs(x[y] - x[-y]))]))`

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question. Solid work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick function that does the same thing as the code you provided.

The code you provided takes the absolute value of the difference between your number and each value in the vector, and compares that the minimum value from that vector. This is the same as the `which.min` function that I use below. I go through my steps below. Hope this helps.

Make up some data

```
a = 1:100
yourNumber = 6
```

Where `Num` is your number, and `x` is a vector

```
getClosest=function(x, Num){
 return(which.min(abs(x-Num)))
}
```

Then if you run this command, it should return the index for the value of the vector that corresponds to the closest value to your specified number.

```
getClosest(x=a, Num=yourNumber)
```