# Detecting the closest value to a whole number in a set of data in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a matrix generated using the fund() method on a .wav file. The entire audio file is 237 seconds, but the matrix contains 20468 rows. I want to have the fundamental frequency at every second of the audio, but the data does not have a clean value for each second. For example:

```
[86,]   0.98690834 0.2450000  
[87,]   0.99851903 0.1807377  
[88,]   1.01012972 0.2808917  
[89,]   1.02174040 0.2463687  
[90,]   1.03335109 0.2505682
```

In this data, the 87th element is the closest to the value at second 1, but its not the exact value. I need to get the values that are closest to the ones at each whole second. I have tried this:

```
timeSection <- 1:(length(fundData)/2)
for(blah in timeSection){
 fundData[blah,1] <- round_any(fundData[blah,1], 0.001, f= floor)
}
```

and it works for some numbers, but not for all, including at the first second.

```
[86,]   0.986 0.2450000  
[87,]   0.998 0.1807377  
[88,]   1.010 0.2808917  
[89,]   1.021 0.2463687
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found what I needed using one of the links @thelatemail provided.

```
tempValue <- which(abs(fundData[,1]-songDuration) == min(abs(fundData[,1]-songDuration)))
```

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968954/return-an-index-from-a-vector-the-index-holds-a-value-which-is-most-near-to-an/14969097 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156872/r-compare-each-data-value-of-a-column-to-rest-of-the-values-in-the-column/30156967

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have access to your data I can't tell you that this works for sure, but I have used a similar function to this before for a similar situation.

```
timeSection <- 1:(length(fundData)/2)
my_fun <- function(x, y){
  which(min(abs(x-y)))
}

rows <- sapply(x = timeSection, my_fun, y = fundData)
df1 <- cbind(timeSection, fundData[rows,])
```

As a side note, you will need to specify the column in the `y` argument of the `sapply()` function

Answer (score 1):

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
df = data.frame(Time = cumsum(1:500/111), Value = abs(rnorm(500)))    

#Find out indices in df$Time of values closest to 1 through 5
sapply(1:5, function(a) which.min(abs(a-df$Time)))
#14 21 25 29 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with data.table

```
library(data.table)

#Create a sample dataset
sample <- data.table(Time = cumsum(1:500/1000), Value = abs(rnorm(500)))

#Order it (not neccessary... was trying a rolling join at first)
setkey(sample, Time)

#Take the nearest second and also the difference in time between exact time and nearest second
sample[, ':=' (difference = abs(Time - round(Time)), Nearest_Second = round(Time))]

#take the minimum time difference grouped by each whole second
sample[, ':=' (mindiff = min(difference), Value = Value) , by = .(Nearest_Second)]

#Only select rows where the difference == minimum difference in time
sample[difference == mindiff, .(Nearest_Second, Time, Value)]
```